# ErrorException Undefined index: 2017_05_14_071616_create_users_table

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.4

I spend lots of time to solve this error but it won't, I just delete migrate and recreate, lots of time drop phpmyadmin database row, composer autoload but I am not able to solve

When I try to migration:refresh or rollback this error happen

> ErrorException  Undefined index: 2017_05_14_071616_create_users_table

The code is as follows (*create_users_table.php*)

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
           Schema::drop('users');
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',50)->unique();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `Schema::drop('users');` inside your `create`?

Comment: i have another error before , somebody suggest me ..

Comment: this is error be the same , use Schema::drop('users'); or not